# Center div horizontally with margin (CSS)

Tags: css, html, center, margin

How can I center horizontally a div which has margin?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="center_me"></div>
</div>


#container{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}

#center_me{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 50px;
    max-width:300px;
    height:100%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

I cant use margin:0 auto, as I want the div to have margin; and the left:50% translateX(-50%) technique doesn't consider the margin. I want to preserve the margin fluidly (always center the div and always preserve the same fixed margin) as the window is resized. Am I missing something very obvious?

http://jsfiddle.net/R3yny/

Just Css,thanks.

Comment: Might be helpful to explain why you want to preserve the margin and/or what the rest of your page is like.

Comment: So if you want to preserver the margin, you'll need to subtract preserved left margin from the `left`. Hence if you've got `margin:0 3%` then your left becomes `left:47%`

Comment: @james-montagne I have a container div which has width:100%, inside it a div which contains a grid (using isotope plugin). In the grid I can specify gutter, but this doesn't make gutter in the grid div.Thats why I want to have a margin in this div.

Comment: @EmileKumfa But then I would have to make the margin fluid. There is no way to keep it fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible, to simply have the margin on another div, that sits inside `#center_me`?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="center_me">
        <div id="i_have_the_margin"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can use `margin:0 auto;` on `#center_me`, like this - http://jsfiddle.net/nickg1/R3yny/3/
(Tested in Opera)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. This would be a solution. There is no way to keep it in just two divs right?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but someone else might know! This is just how I would solve it. ;)

Comment: Lets see if someone can come up with it. Thanks!

Comment: Great, also the fact of using margin 0 auto instead of transform

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if your element is offset from center with a margin it cannot be centered. What it sounds like you want to do it hold an element in a central-ish place on webpage with a responsive design.

The best way to get that done is to use margin widths as percentages, and eyeball your div until it looks like its about where you want it. Check this sample out- it's really simple:

http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/oHGAF

CSS:

```
.hero-text-area-container {
  background: #d6ffd1;
  float: left;
  margin: 0% 30%;
  padding-top: 20em;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I would like the margin to be fixed